# How to break line or wrap content inside ScrollView depending on a condition

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I want to achieve something like in the 1st image, where view will be placed in the same line if a condition is true, if not the next view must be placed in the next line.

[image]

In my app i have now this result:

[image]

The code for that :

```js
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.exercisesContainer}>
            {item.category_workouts.map((exercice, index) => (
              <Exercises
                key={index}
                img={AssetsManager.Images.exerciseImg}
                title={exercice.workout_name}
                level={exercice.level}
              />
            ))}

//
//
 exercisesContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
```

Comment: What do you want your outcome to be. I don't see anything wrong with what you have here, its what I would expect. What kind of conditions are you planning to use to determine whether an item is on its own line or not? Your question is missing many important pieces of information.

Comment: The condition is related to the level of the exercice, if two views represent two exercices of the same level they would be placed in the same line, otherwise the next one must go down.

Comment: That doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me, maybe if you showed us what you want your given example to look like it will make more sense.

Comment: Sorry to confuse you, i want my app (with the workouts) to look like the first image the one with loops ...

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to my issue. Using a function i calculate the with of each element depending on his prop `level`.
Examples:

- if the level of the first element is 'beginner' and the next one is 'medium', the first element will take '100%' width thus taking the hole line and because he is the only 'beginner' element.
- if we have three elements with the same level maybe 'advanced' they will be given '33%' width each.

here is my function, however it needs some refactoring :

```js
const getExercicesWidth = exercices => {
    const exercicesLevels = [];
    exercices.forEach(exercice => {
      exercicesLevels.push(exercice.level);
    });
    let widthArray = [];
    let counter = 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < exercicesLevels.length; i++) {
      if (i === 0) {
        continue;
      }
      if (exercicesLevels[i] == exercicesLevels[i - 1]) {
        counter++;
      } else {
        widthArray.push(counter);
        counter = 1;
      }
    }
    widthArray.push(counter);
    const percentageWidthArray = [];
    widthArray.forEach(number => {
      let c = number;
      while (c > 0) {
        percentageWidthArray.push(`${Math.round(100 / number)}%`);
        c--;
      }
    });
    return percentageWidthArray;
  };
```

the result now is like this:

[image]